# JS function's parameter without argument

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

```
var num = [2,4,6,8,10,12];
function print (n) {
console.log (n);
}
num.forEach(print);
```

My understanding was we give function's parameters to pass in arguments But above code is not passing in any arguments.
I know the output, Question is how array of num's each value is passing into parameter 'n', while im just calling in function it self.
To simplify
How parameter 'n' is getting each value of array num ?
Thank You

Comment: Your function is being called by `.forEach()`, which passes parameters when it calls the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'print' function that you are passing as an argument for 'forEach' is a callback function with a specific set of arguments. When forEach iterates over each item of the array it passes the currentValue of the array during a specific iteration as the first argument to the callback function (i.e., 'print' in your case.)

Following is the general syntax of array forEach:

```
 array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the forEach method will look like the following

```
foreach(this: array, fn : (element) => void) : void {
   for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { 
     fn(this[i])
   }
}
```

So is the for each method that is responsible to pass each element of the array as the parameter `n`

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach()` maps the function which it receives to the elements of the object which is invoking it.

In your case, the elements of the `num` array are automatically passed as arguments to the `print` function, as `num` is invoking its `.forEach()` method and `print` is the function being supplied as an argument to the `.forEach()` method.